# Comparing multiple images in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to do a pixel-by-pixel comparison of 20 png images stored in a cell array. For each pixel position (i,j) I want to find the pixel with the largest and smallest value from amongst the 20 images.

My current implementation seems to work, but as it's just a bunch of nested for loops it takes several minutes to finish executing. I'm looking for a more efficient method, does anyone have a suggestion? My current code is below.

```
min = 256;
max = -1;

for j = 1: xMax
    for k = 1: yMax
        for p = 1: 20
            if imageArray{p}(j,k) > max
                max = imageArray{p}(j,k);
            end
            if imageArray{p}(j,k) < min
                min = imageArray{p}(j,k);
            end
        end
        minImg(j,k) = min;
        maxImg(j,k) = max;
        min = 256;
        max = -1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the sizes of all those images to be the same, here's one efficient approach -

```
%// Get dimensions of each image
[nrows,ncols] = size(imageArray{1}) 

%// Convert the cell array to a 3D numeric array for vectorized operations
im = reshape(cell2mat(imageArray),nrows,ncols,[])

%// Use MATLAB builtins min and max along the third dimension for final output
minImg = min(im,[],3)
maxImg = max(im,[],3)
```

Comment: So minImg/maxImg are nrows*ncols matrices made up of the results of finding the min/max pixel values for all nrows*ncols pixel positions? I.e minImg(1,1) is the smallest of the 20 (1,1) pixels we compared? Sorry, I'm new to matlab and am having trouble figuring out what the last two lines do.

Comment: @Adam Exactly, that's the result you must expect with these vectorized operations. Same goes for `maxImg`, that is each element in `maxImg` would be the maximum for each pixel across all 20 images.